# Terraform AWS: Access Lambda's function URL inside the function itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I have a Python API deployed on AWS Lambda. The API calls OAuth, which means that the API should send its own URL in the request; and lambda URLs are generated upon request.

I'm using Terraform and specifically the [lambda module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest) (for easier deployment as I don't have to package anything, it just takes the directory).

```yaml
module "registration_api_tf" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  function_name      = "registration_api_tf"
  handler            = "lambda_function.lambda_handler"
  runtime            = "python3.9"
  source_path        = "../src/registration/"
  attach_policy_json = true
  policy_json = # ...
  create_lambda_function_url    = true
  # ... other configs
  environment_variables = {
    client_id     = var.client_id
    client_secret = var.client_secret
    # own_url       = module.registration_api_tf.lambda_function_url
  }
}
```

As you can see, I was trying to set the own_url env variable, but terraform flags it as circular. I tried using `self.lambda_function_url`, but again terraform objected to using `self`.

I believe this is possible to do using a `local_exec` provisioner, but I'd rather not add more local dependencies (aws-cli) to the project.

Is there any workaround/module to solve this?

Comment: cant you use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function_url to create a url using the functions name first then use the resources `function_url` attribute in your lambda? I am not sure if this resource will create before the function exists but you could try. Also you should move the function name to a local and refer to in both the lambda module and function url.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle what you describe would actually create a circular reference. You're actually describing exactly what is happening in the question already, it's just not clear since it's happening inside a module.

Comment: Well, when called before creating the function it raises `ResourceNotFoundException`. And obviously referencing the resource would be circular again ...

Comment: @MarkB yeah thats the part i wasnt sure of so suggested to test it. Some AWS resources can be created ahead of time and linked together later but seems this is not one of those

Comment: Just as a reference: if this issue by me will be ever closed as resolved, you'll have much simpler way. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/31405 Consider reacting on issue to demonstrate interest in implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the Lambda function to determine its own URL by itself, using the AWS API ([boto3 docs here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/get_function_url_config.html)). To call that, you'll need the Lambda function name; [this is available in the context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) that your function is invoked with.

So the process would look like

- Retrieve function name from context object
- Call API to get function URL
- If the function URL doesn't exist (either not ready yet or incorrectly configured), fail with an error
- Otherwise you now have the URL for this function, and you can carry on as you intended.

Comment: Absolute legend! Just the workaround I was looking for. I've never paid much attention to the context variable or boto Lambda client, really appreciate the links.

Comment: API calls are not that cheap: you'll get execution time overhead. If you want to invoke the function with some parameters, it may turn out that you double your execution time to fetch static information known in advance. I just deploy terraform twice to get function deployed first and then add it's alias ARN to environment - it's a dirty hack, of course, that slightly breaks usual terraform workflow, but it saves actual execution time.

Comment: @STerliakov Sure, if you're really counting every millisecond of operation, you might not want to make an extra API call every time. Something like what you have described is possible, but another option is to cache the result within the Lambda. This won't help if you only have very occasional invocations, so are cold-starting all the time, but if you only have occasional invocations, there's no point in worrying about the cost of an extra API call.

Comment: Cached solution may be performant enough, indeed. Thanks for the idea! I have secrets manager calls cached, but decided not to go this way for lambda identification for some reason...